# How can I avoid animations getting "dancy"?

Tags: animation

I've done this [animated GIF image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EuCPk.jpg). The trouble with it is that it gets "dancy" as you can see. For the organization of the items, I'm using the following code:

> [image]

Which can be copied here:

```
TableForm[{
{TableForm[
{{
  Style[Length[c], "Title", 16], Style[Hino[[n]], "Title"]
  }}
, TableAlignments -> Center]},
ListPlot[Table[Count[c, A[[n]]], {n, 1, 26}], AxesOrigin -> {0, 0},
PlotRange -> {{0, 27}, {0, 155}}, ImageSize -> 800,
Filling -> {Axis},
 Epilog ->
Inset[Plot[9.02, {x, 1, 26.1}, ImageSize -> 800,
  PlotRange -> {{0, 27}, {0, 155}}, Axes -> False,
  PlotTheme -> "Monochrome"]], Axes -> False,
PlotStyle -> Directive[Black, PointSize[0.01]]]

}, TableAlignments -> Center]
```

What can I do to avoid the animation getting "dancy" like this?

Comment: why not  get rid of `TableForm` and simply use `ListPlot[...]` with the option `PlotLabel ->Row[{ Style[Length[c], "Title", 16], Style[Hino[[n]], "Title"] }, Spacer[5]]`  ?

Comment: ... and `GridLines -> {None, {9.02}}` instead of `Epilog ->Inset[...]`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To replicate the *dancy* plot with fake data:

```
hino = RandomWord["Noun", 50];

lpdata = RandomInteger[150, 26]; 

frames = Table[TableForm[{{TableForm[{{Style[RandomInteger[500], "Title", 16],
         Style[hino[[i]], "Title"]}}, TableAlignments -> Center]}, 
    ListPlot[lpdata, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, 
     PlotRange -> {{0, 27}, {0, 155}}, ImageSize -> 500, 
     Filling -> {Axis}, 
     Epilog -> Inset[Plot[9.02, {x, 1, 26.1}, ImageSize -> 500, 
        PlotRange -> {{0, 27}, {0, 155}}, Axes -> False, 
        PlotTheme -> "Monochrome"]], Axes -> False, 
     PlotStyle -> Directive[Black, PointSize[0.01]]]}, 
   TableAlignments -> Center], {i, 50}];

Export["dancingplot.gif", frames, AnimationRepetitions -> Infinity]
```

[image]

If you *have to* use `TableForm` you can wrap the inner `TableForm` with `Pane` with a specific `ImageSize` so that the vertical size of the cell does not change depending on whether the title word has characters with ascenders/descenders. That is, use

```
Pane[TableForm[{{Style[RandomInteger[500], "Title", 16], 
    Style[hino[[i]], "Title"]}}, TableAlignments -> Center], 
 ImageSize -> {300, 50}, Alignment -> Center]
```

to get

[image]

If you don't have to use `TableForm`, then you can simply use `ListPlot` with the options `PlotLabel` and `GridLines`:

```
frames3 = Table[ListPlot[lpdata, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, 
    PlotRange -> {{0, 27}, {0, 155}}, ImageSize -> 500, 
    Filling -> {Axis}, 
    PlotLabel -> Pane[Row[{Style[RandomInteger[500], "Title", 16], 
        Style[hino[[i]], "Title"]}, Spacer[15]], 
      ImageSize -> {500, 100}, Alignment -> {Center, Center}], 
    GridLines -> {None, {{9.02, Directive[Thick, Black]}}}, 
    Axes -> False, PlotStyle -> Directive[Black, PointSize[0.01]]], {i, 50}];

Export["dancingplot3.gif", frames3, AnimationRepetitions -> Infinity]
```

[image]